# Executing query with wrong NULL operator in where clause

Tags: postgresql, null, where-clause

I'm wondering what exactly is happening when I run SQL like:

```
UPDATE pgbench_accounts
SET filler = 'test'
WHERE aid = NULL;
```

Does PostgreSQL do seq scan in this case? Explain analyze differs depending on PostgreSQL version.
On 9.3 looks like:

```
"Update on pgbench_accounts  (cost=0.00..6266.00 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..6266.00 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        One-Time Filter: NULL::boolean"
"        ->  Seq Scan on pgbench_accounts  (cost=0.00..6266.00 rows=1 width=26) (never executed)"
```

But in previous versions lacks of "(never executed)" so is PostgreSQL smart enough to not executing scans if operator was wrong?

Comment: It is not that the operator is "wrong". What happens is that comparing anything to null will evaluate to null so no rows will be returned. The planner can figure that out. I guess even in older versions.

Comment: operator is wrong, because it's not that what we are asking for. I need to be sure about that, second solution is IF ... THEN statement, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Borys And what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know if PostgreSQL in this case will do seq scan or not.

Comment: Create a really big table, and check the total execution time for such a query. If "doing" a seq scan on million of rows still only takes 0.02 milliseconds it's very likely it wasn't really executed

Comment: @Borys Then what is the other solution you mention? Question "will it do a seq scan or not?" does not have solution. Do you want to force a seq scan?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did, but still wondering how it's gonna behave in other cases, other tables, so I would prefer to know what's happening on planer level/

Comment: @Borys, what "other versions" are you talking about? I have tested it back to 8.4 and the result was the same, the Seq Scan got "never executed" because of "One-Time Filter".

Comment: @Borys Your best bet for a definitive answer is to study the relevant planner code. It's not easy reading, though.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want it to update all rows when the parameter is null

```
update pgbench_accounts
set filler = 'test'
where aid = :parameter or :parameter is null;
```

If what you want is to treat null as if it where a common value

```
update pgbench_accounts
set filler = 'test'
where aid is not distinct from :parameter;
```

Comment: it's not what I'm asking about. I need to know if seq scan gonna be executed or not.